# Fresh installed Visual Studio 2017 won't create C++ project with error 0x80041fe2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 (current time: August 2018). I only need C++ so I picked C++ component and deselected everything listed in "optional" items. Then after the installation, I cannot even create any C++ projects including both console and desktop projects. It gives me a error dialog of "Exception from hresult 0x80041fe2".

I did a search online. This question, [visual studio and qt: HRESULT: 0x80041FE2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399486/visual-studio-and-qt-hresult-0x80041fe2), seems close but it's QT related, so it's different.

I did eventually find a solution. Will answer my own question below.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is probably a Visual Studio installation bug. The "Optional" components are really not totally optional. I then picked the following Optional components and then it works:

- Just-in-Time debugger
- VC++ 2017 version 15.8 v14.15 latest v141 tools
- C++ profiling tools
- C++/CLI support
- VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop

Almost certainly not all of these are needed. But I don't want to spend time to find out which "Optional" is actually not optional...

Comment: This is just a guess, but if any if these is absolutely required, it's likely the latest v141 tools, because you need them to actually compile any C++ code.

Comment: I finally get it worked with these "optional" components: 1. `Just-in-Time debugger`, 2. `VC++ 2017 version 15.8 v14.15 latest v141 tools` and 3. `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)`.

Comment: @Emadpres What os are you using? It seems that you can't create UWP applications/msvs solutions in non-windows 10 systems.